# Find the minimal average of any slice containing at least two elements in an array

Tags: c

The full question is:[Min Average Two Slice Codility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635397/min-average-two-slice-codility)

I don't understand why my code doesn't work.

I know the correct answer, but I can't find a contra example for my code:

```
struct partaverg {
    long double min;
    int slice;
};

long long sumfun(int arr[], int N) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        sum += arr[i];
    return sum;
}

int solution(int A[], int N) {
    long long sum;
    long double new_average;

    int left = 0;
    int right = N - 1;
    long double numofnum;
    long double leftaverg, rightaverg;
    sum = sumfun(A, N);
    struct partaverg result;
    new_average = result.min = sum / (long double)N;
    result.slice = 0;
    while (left + 1 < right) {
        numofnum = right - left;
        leftaverg = (sum - A[left]) / numofnum;
        rightaverg = (sum - A[right]) / numofnum;
        if (leftaverg > rightaverg) {
            sum -= A[right--];
            new_average = rightaverg;
        } else {
            sum -= A[left++];
            new_average = leftaverg;
        }
        if (result.min > new_average) {
            result.min=new_average;
            result.slice=left;
        }
    }
    return result.slice;
}
```

Comment: *I don't understand why my code doesn't work.* Could you be more precise and tell us what does not work?

Comment: Codility writes that there are arrays that this code won't work, but I can't find them.
https://app.codility.com/c/run/trainingMHPHRM-383/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your algorithm comes when then current slice holds the same number at the left-most and the right-most position. Which number shall you remove? The left or the right?

Your current algorithm always remove the left number but that may be incorrect. Consider:

```
int arr[4] = {1,9, 10, 1 };

// left average = (1 + 9 + 10) /3
// right average = (9 + 10 + 1) /3
```

The left average and the right average is the same so your code removes the left number and proceeds with this slice:

```
{9, 10, 1 };
```

which is wrong. Now you can no longer reach the correct result which is:

```
{1,9};
```